# Infinte Horizontal scrolling in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, infinite-scroll

I was able to get vertical infinite scrolling working with redux-infinte-scroller ()

```
    <InfiniteScroll` containerHeight = {this.props.height} items={this._renderMessages()} loadMore={this._loadMore.bind(this)}>
      this.render_items();
     </InfinteScroll>
```

However while trying to implement horizontal infinite scroll with

```
    <InfiniteScroll horizontal = {true} containerHeight = {this.props.height} items={this._renderMessages()} loadMore={this._loadMore.bind(this)}>

    this.render_items();
   </InfinteScroll>
```

does not work.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Redux-infinite-scroll is used for vertical scrolling only, not for horizontal scrolling.

The `horizontal` prop only used to also take into account horizontal scrolling (due to the width of the content), while scrolling vertically.